# Need to merge objects with the same keys but different values

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to find the shortest and most beautiful way to convert an array of objects with the same values of the category key:

```
[{
  "label": "Apple",
  "category": "Fruits"
}, {
  "label": "Orange",
  "category": "Fruits"
}, {
  "label": "Potato",
  "category": "Vegetables"
}, {
  "label": "Tomato",
  "category": "Vegetables"
}, {
  "label": "Cherry",
  "category": "Berries"
}]
```

to the one with grouped labels from the same category:

```
[{
  "label": ["Apple", "Orange"],
  "category": "Fruits"
}, {
  "label": ["Potato", "Tomato"],
  "category": "Vegetables"
}, {
  "label": ["Cherry"],
  "category": "Berries"
}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an object as hash table and group the categories.

```js
var data = [{ "label": "Apple", "category": "Fruits" }, { "label": "Orange", "category": "Fruits" }, { "label": "Potato", "category": "Vegetables" }, { "label": "Tomato", "category": "Vegetables" }, { "label": "Cherry", "category": "Berries" }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.category]) {
        this[a.category] = { label: [], category: a.category };
        grouped.push(this[a.category]);
    }
    this[a.category].label.push(a.label);
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do this using lodash:

```
_(coll)
  .groupBy('category')
  .map((v, k) => ({
    category: k,
    label: _.map(v, 'label')
  }))
  .value()
```

Basically, [groupBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#groupBy) creates an object with unique categories as keys. Then, [map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#map) turns this object back into an array, where each item has the structure you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt to solve your problem

```js
var result = [];
var input = [{
  "label": "Apple",
  "category": "Fruits"
}, {
  "label": "Orange",
  "category": "Fruits"
}, {
  "label": "Potato",
  "category": "Vegetables"
}, {
  "label": "Tomato",
  "category": "Vegetables"
}, {
  "label": "Cherry",
  "category": "Berries"
}];
var cat = [];
for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if(!cat[input[i].category]) {
    cat[input[i].category] = {category: input[i].category, label:[input[i].label]};
    result.push(cat[input[i].category]);
  } else {
    cat[input[i].category].label.push(input[i].label);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```